# Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <xxViewController: 0xaa82610>

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ads

I tried to add TapforTap Ads to my iPhone app, the ad appear but I show this message in console "Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for ." after any navigation of pages and then the app crash, the below code for calling TapForTap Ads. How I can solve this problem?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    CGFloat y = self.view.frame.size.height - 50.0;

    TapForTapAdView *adView = [[TapForTapAdView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, y, 320, 50) delegate: self];
    [self.view addSubview: adView];

    [TapForTapAppWall prepare];
    [TapForTapAppWall showWithRootViewController: self]; // or possibly self.navigationController
}
```

Thanks A lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know it for sure. But try this:

```
- (void) ShowTapAd {

    CGFloat y = self.view.frame.size.height - 50.0;

    TapForTapAdView *adView = [[TapForTapAdView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, y, 320, 50) delegate: self];
    [self.view addSubview: adView];

    [TapForTapAppWall prepare];
    [TapForTapAppWall showWithRootViewController: self]; // or possibly self.navigationController

}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(showTapAd) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
}
```

The run time warning that you got appears when you hussle with two (or more) segue, Navigation Controller push or present modally types of processes. Meaning when you initiate one before the former was totally finished.

I am surprised that those things can happen when you call something within viewDidLoad. So you may find out that the root cause is not located within the code sniplet that you have shown. But if it is then this could do the trick.

What it does: 
It just makes sure that your setup of the ad view is performed after viewDidLoad is properly finished. As viewDidLoad runs on the main tread as all UI related stuff does (or should do), the current appearance transistion should be finised by then.

Hope, this helps. Again, it is just a guess.

Comment: Thank u Hermann Klecker, I agree with u the reason is two Navigation Controller Push, but this warning I show in viewDidLoad after add your code "Instance method '-performSelectorOnMainThread:' not found (return type defaults to 'id')"

Comment: Hi Hermann Klecker, in viewDidLoad I write the below method and then the warning is remove in console, but the app still crash      [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(ShowTapAd) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];

Comment: Well, there is no `performSelectorOnMainThread:` It is called `performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:wailtUntilDone:` I have changed the answer accordingly. You find the documentation in NSObject Class Reference.

Comment: So, how does it crash this time?

Comment: There is no warning, after some minutes the app crash, I dont know the reason, what I can do?

Comment: Did you add an 'all exceptions" breakpoint? On Throw?. And press continue ones or twice then the message comes up.

Comment: Well, this was rather a suggestion than a question :)

Comment: Thank u Hermann Klecker, there is no message come up only in console (lldb).